# Html scroll function not working on routed page

Tags: html, angular

I have an Angular project that is bilingual. I have the main page, and then a routed component with the same content but in a different language. I have different ids for both, but for some reason in the routed page the scroll function doesn't work, instead it redirects me to my main page.

This is how the code looks on the main page:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.argentina.gob.ar/economia/conocimiento/argentina-programa" target="_blank">
            <img src="../../../assets/APLogo.png"  alt="" width="110" height="60" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">

        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link link-light" href="#acerca-de">Sobre mi</a>
                </li>
```

And here is the place to where it successfully scrolls:

```
<section class="container-fluid about-section" id="acerca-de">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">
            <img src="../../../assets/foto-de-perfil.jpg" class="img-fluid perfil" alt="foto de perfil">
        </div>
        <div class="tarjeta col-md" >
            <h2 class="titulo" >About me</h2>
            <h3>Hello! I'm Bob the builder <br><br> <span class="presentacion"> blabla </span></h3>
            <p class="card-text" id="text-acercade">blabla</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is how the one in the routed page looks:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.argentina.gob.ar/economia/conocimiento/argentina-programa" target="_blank">
            <img class="logo-english" src="../../../assets/APLogo.png"  alt="" width="110" height="60" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">

        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link link-light" href="#about">About me</a>
                </li>
```

Here is the place where it's supposed to scroll but fails:

```
<section class="container-fluid about-section" id="about">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">
            <img src="../../../assets/foto-de-perfil.jpg" class="img-fluid perfil" alt="foto de perfil">
        </div>
        <div class="tarjeta col-md" >
            <h2 class="titulo" >About me</h2>
            <h3>Hello! I'm Bob the builder <br><br> <span class="presentacion">blabla</span></h3>
            <p class="card-text" id="text-acercade">blabla</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Is there something about pathing I'm not understanding? I did mess around with routing modules without really understanding what I was doing. The buttons work fine and scroll on the main page, but on the routed one even though the ids are different it just redirects me to the main page. Any help would be deeply appreciated.